# Couldn't match type error even with type constraint

Tags: haskell

How come the following

```
foo :: MonadIO m => m ()
foo = print "hi"
```

causes the following error

> Couldn't match type ‘m’ with ‘IO’
>         ‘m’ is a rigid type variable bound by
>           the type signature for:
>             foo :: forall (m :: * -> *). MonadIO m => m ()
>           at foo.hs:57:8
>         Expected type: m ()
>           Actual type: IO ()

As far as I know, shouldn't the MonadIO constraint allow this to work since IO () should be equal to a MonadIO ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`IO` is not equal to `MonadIO`.

`MonadIO` is a typeclass that, in plain terms, means that the monad in question can perform IO operations. In practice, since `IO` monad is "magic", this can mean only one of two things: the monad in question is `IO` itself, or the monad in question *wraps* `IO` in some way.

To express this idea of wrapping, the `MonadIO` type class has a method `liftIO :: IO a -> m a`, which lets you take an `IO` operation and "lift" it (or, if you prefer, "wrap" it) into the monad `m`, whatever that is.

So, to fix your code, all you need is `liftIO`:

```
foo :: MonadIO m => m ()
foo = liftIO $ print "hi"
```